# Why does an empty OpenGL program uses a full core?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm using an `OpenGL` library for C# called `OpenTK`. I made a new `GameWindow` and ran it on 60 fps and 60 ups. And it has nothing to do and uses a full processor core.

```
GameWindow window = new GameWindow();
window.Run(60, 60);
```

With that code it uses constant 25% of 4 cores.[image: Processor using constant 25%]

When I call `SwapBuffers` on every frame, the CPU usage stays around 25% as well.

```
GameWindow window = new GameWindow();
window.RenderFrame += (sender, e) =>
{
    window.SwapBuffers();
};
window.Run(60, 60);
```

[image: CPU stays around 25%]

I've seen many OpenGL games, but none of them used a full core when the application was idling.
From my understanding, all the processing power goes for better and more precise timing.

What do I do to only use the necessary resources and not more?

Comment: why should an empty endless loop _not_ use a full core? OpenGL doesn't use anything without you calling GL functions.

Comment: @derhass because I told it to run only 60 times a second? Should I use Thread.Sleep?

Comment: Well, I don't know OpenTK, but if it does not call `SwapBuffers` behind your back, you are technically not rendering a single frame, and no sort of frame limiting / vsync will have a chance to have any effect

Comment: @derhass `SwapBuffers` didn't help. (see the edited question for more info)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a quirk on how OpenTK is programmed. When you call .Run() it basically runs an infinite tight loop of processing window events plus 60 times per second it'll call your render frame method. You can see this loop on their [Github repo](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/3.x/src/OpenTK/GameWindow.cs#L366):

```cs
while (true)
{
    ProcessEvents();
    if (Exists && !IsExiting)
    {
        if (isSingleThreaded)
        {
            DispatchUpdateFrame(watchRender);
        }
        DispatchRenderFrame();
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

in DispatchRenderFrame() it tests if enough time has passed to call your render frame method.

In summary, you do need to enable VSync (`window.VSync = OpenTK.VSyncMode.On`) + SwapBuffers or implement your own Thread.Sleep() if you don't want it to eat one core.

By the way, I personally had weird issues with VSync not correctly applying on 32bit applications with a geforce card. If that happens to you, the only thing i figured out was to switch to a 64 bit application and/or create a nvidia profile manually or programatically using [SOP.CS](http://drivenbynostalgia.com/files/SOP.cs)